# CoffeeScript class results in empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, electron

I have a file 'a.coffee', with the following code:

```
class Options
  options:
    # ...

  setOption: (name, value) ->
    # ...

  getOption: (name) ->
    # ...

# Export the Options class.
module.exports = Options
```

And file 'b.coffee':

```
Options = require './a'
console.log new Options()
```

Of course, it is expected that when I run b.coffee, I will see this output:

```
{
  options: ...,
  setOption: function (name, value),
  getOption: function (name)
}
```

But instead, I get `{}`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expectations are wrong. Everything at the class level goes in the object's prototype so given this:

```
class C
  p: 6
  m: ->
o = new C
```

the object `o` will be empty because there are no instance variables but if you look at the "class" (via [`Object.prototype.constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) to get the "class" and `::` to get the prototype):

```
o.constructor::p
```

you'll see things.

If you add some instance variables (i.e. something that really is part of your object):

```
class C
  constructor: -> @p = 6
```

then you'll see them in the object:

```
c = new C
console.log c
# { p: 6 } will appear in the console
```

Comment: But this seems to go against what is demonstrated at http://coffeescript.org/#classes

Comment: How so? I don't see any discrepancies. You can `o = new Options; o.getOption('x')` just fine due to prototypical inheritance.

Comment: Then it seems the problem I am having is different from what I thought - I had a more detailed class here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/htmlguy/elapse/master/src/Options.coffee and nodejs was reporting an error when the getOption function is called. I suppose I'll have to make a new question for my real problem.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your `getOption`. BTW, "wether" is a ram or goat with a certain anatomical modification, the word you're looking for is "whether".

Comment: Thank you. I fixed the actual problem on my own, still not sure exactly what it was.